# How to disable Key repeat except for Backspace and Delete keys?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard

System: Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon.

How to disable Key repeat except for <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keys?

I find repeat keys really annoying, so I decided to do something with it today:

[image: Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon - repeat key settings]

But now I can't use <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> properly.

Any ideas?